# Oriceon OAuth Laravel 5 - Call to undefined method OAuth::consumer()

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth

I am implementing OAuth service provider for Laravel 5 [oriceon/oauth-5-laravel](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel)

I am getting this error "Call to undefined method OAuth::consumer()".
I was following the readme steps for installation:

- I have added "oriceon/oauth-5-laravel": "dev-master" into composer.json. Then I run composer update, no errors.
- I have added "Artdarek\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider::class," into 'providers' array app.php
- I have added "'OAuth' => Artdarek\OAuth\Facade\OAuth::class," into 'aliases' array in app.php

Here is my config/oauth-5-laravel.php:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | oAuth Config
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Storage
     */
    'storage' => '\\OAuth\\Common\\Storage\\Session',

    /**
     * Consumers
     */
    'consumers' => [

        'Facebook' => [
            'client_id'     => '',
            'client_secret' => '',
            'scope'         => [],
        ],

        'Google' => [
            'client_id'     => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_SECRET_ID'),
            'scope'         => ['userinfo_email', 'userinfo_profile'],
        ],

    ]

];
```

Here is my GoogleController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use OAuth;

class GoogleController extends Controller
{

    public function loginWithGoogle(Request $request)
    {
        // get data from request
        $code = $request->get('code');

        // get google service
        $googleService = \OAuth::consumer('Google');

        // check if code is valid

        // if code is provided get user data and sign in
        if ( ! is_null($code))
        {
            // This was a callback request from google, get the token
            $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);

            // Send a request with it
            $result = json_decode($googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'), true);

            $message = 'Your unique Google user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
            echo $message. "<br/>";

            //Var_dump
            //display whole array.
            dd($result);
        }
        // if not ask for permission first
        else
        {
            // get googleService authorization
            $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

            // return to google login url
            return redirect((string)$url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in php is class OAuth which was inicialized after oriceons OAuth.